# Use value from a text box as a parameter in a pass through query in Access

Tags: ms-access, pass-through

I have a Firebird database where I used a Stored Procedure named SP_SALES to generate quite a complex sales report. I now want to consolidate the sales reports from a few DB's into one report using MS Access. In Access I created a normal pass though query acting as a linked table and will do this for each database from where I can easily consolidate the reports. My issue now is that I have FROM DATE and TO DATE parameters in my stored procedure.  So my pass through query in Access looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM SP_SALES ('2019/01/01' , '2019/12/31')
```

The user should be able to define the FROM DATE and the TO DATE when pulling my consolidated report. So I have created a userform where this can be populated. The userform is named frm_CONSOLIDATED_SALES and the date boxes are named txt_FROM_DATE and txt_TO-DATE respectively. So I changed my Access query to look as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM SP_SALES ([Forms]![frm_CONSOLIDATED_SALES][txt_FROM_DATE] , [Forms][frm_CONSOLIDATED_SALES][txt_TO_DATE])
```

I am however getting a TOKEN UNKNOWN error when running the query. I am trying to stay clear from doing this in VBA as I am not sure how to do a pass through query in VBA. However, if I need to go that route any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How should Firebird know anything about your database when receiving a pass-through query? It has no idea what `[Forms]![frm_CONSOLIDATED_SALES][txt_FROM_DATE]` is about other than invalid syntax.

So, before passing the query, adjust its *SQL property* to:

```
SELECT * FROM SP_SALES ('2019/01/01' , '2019/12/31')
```

using something like:

```
YourQuery.SQL = "SELECT * FROM SP_SALES ('" & Format([txt_From_Date], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "' , '" & Format([txt_To_Date], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "')"
```

Comment: Thanks, that does not make a lot of sense. However, does this mean I will need to execute the query in VBA?

Comment: No ... you can leave it for later use; the change will be persistent. Just adjust it whenever you plan to use it and you are unsure if the parameters have been set as required.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to meet my requirement with your assistance.